# Error executing mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

`mysql_fetch_array` is not working. Everything looks fine. I don't know where I am doing something  wrong.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` limit $start,$limit";//if echo gives o/p Resource id #14 

$resultw = mysql_query($sql);
while($gup=mysql_fetch_array($resultw))//if echo gives o/p Array
{
//if echo $gup['to']; gives o/p vicky.0989hyd@gmail.com;

$anusha=mysql_query("select * from users where email='$gup[to]'");//if echo gives o/p Resource id #15

    while($resulter = mysql_fetch_array('$anusha'))//here is what iam getting error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in
 {
    }
}
```

Can someone help me find out my error in my `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: **mysql_fetch_array($anusha)**

Comment: for some reason you've wrapped `$anusha` in single quotes. don't do it.

Comment: i tried no use still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if there are any errors in your query with: `mysql_error();`
This function, returns the last accured error in your mysql-related functions.
Just use this syntax:

```
$resultw = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$gup=mysql_fetch_array($resultw) or die(mysql_error());
while($gup)//if echo gives o/p Array
{
    $email=$gup['to'];
    $anusha=mysql_query("select * from users where email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    //check $anusha here before pass it to mysql_fetch_array function
    ...
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in

Comment: Are you using `mysql_`* or `mysqli_*`? Cause these are different!

Comment: i have changed no use

Comment: When it gives you the warning you said, which line does it points to?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home3/zhzfvdvu/public_html/account/khatik-shaadi-recent.php on line 278

Comment: while($resulter = mysql_fetch_array('$anusha') )error in this line

Comment: Putting quotes around a variable, makes it a string! Now, if you use single quotes, you can not pass the variable, but double quotes lets you change the variable name with its value. You can see the difference in the output of the following: `$a=12;echo '$a is $a' . "but \$a is $a";`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to understand the following code very carefully. This is currently being used on my Social networking site, and I hope this solves your problem.

---

```
$st= "SELECT* FROM users WHERE username='$you'";
$result=mysqli_query ($con,$st);
$count=mysqli_num_rows ($result);

if($count==0){echo "<b>Profile not found! </b> ";}
else {echo "<b>Your Profile..</b>";}
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {  echo "Username-<b>". $row ['uname']. "</b>";    echo "sent you this message";
echo "<p id='sms'>". $row ['sms']. "</p>";
```

Comment: what might be $con in my programme

Comment: $con is connection of the database

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Answer (score 0):

Try this way... i think you are messing with single and double quotes

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` limit $start,$limit";
$resultw = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$resultw) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($gup=mysql_fetch_array($resultw))//if echo gives o/p Array
{
$email=$gup['to'];
$anusha=mysql_query("select * from users where email='$email'");
if (!$anusha) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
//check $anusha here before pass it to mysql_fetch_array function
while($resulter = mysql_fetch_array($anusha))
 {
  //do what you want to do man
 }
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in

Comment: Hey, what api are you using MYSQL or MYSQLi,first check that, you can't mix both of them

Comment: mysql iam using i.e xampp

Comment: change to mysql_fetch_array still failed

Comment: echo "$anusha";//give o/p Resource id #15

Comment: You are getting resource id #15 because $result is an resource